# Error al instalar proyectos existente de laravel en mi pc

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, laravel

estoy instalando un proyecto en laravel en mi pc, descargado de github, estoy ejecutando composer install, pero me da este error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando xampp como servidor local en windows 7. Agradecería su ayuda

Comment: te esta indicando que la extensión mcrypt no esta disponible en tu sistema

Comment: Como la instalo?

Comment: fijate si no está comentada en el php.ini, xampp 7.+ la trae instalada y activada para web, tal vez necesites activarla para el cli

Comment: En el archivo php.ini de tu instalación de XAMPP descomenta las extensiones que te pide Laravel : mcrypt